# C# Regex - Match comma delimited list of tuples

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to match the sub-strings enclosed by {...} where the inside content is a set of n-tuples each separated by a comma (example is shown below). The regex pattern acquires an expected result, but doesn't fully express the full rules needed.

**Rules**

- **Brace**: sub-strings enclosed by `{...}`, but no nested sub braces such as `{ ... {..}}`
- **Comma**: The element `{(a,b)(t,s),(u,v)}` is not in the matches since it's missing a comma between `(a,b)` and `(t,s)`.
- **Tuple**: The elements of an n-tuple can be any text not containing a comma or brace or parentheses. E.g: `(a,b, test element)` is ok but not `(a,b, {ab})`

But the regex pattern used not quite working.

For example, if I move the comma in `{(a,b)(t,s),(u,v)}` to make it `{(a,b),(t,s)(u,v)}` this element appears *as a match* even though now the tuples `(t,s)` and `(u,v)` are not separated by comma.

**Valid Results**

> {(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s and q,t),(u,v,y)}
>
> {(a,b),(c,d,e)}
>
> {(a,b),(c+1,d)}

```
string st = 
"abc+{(a,b,c),(d,e,f),(r,s and q,t),(u,v,y)}+c-{(a,b)(t,s),(u,v)}+e+{(a,b),(c,d,e)}+rst+{(a,b),(c,d)}";

Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{\([^\)\(]+\)[,]+\(.*?\)}");

foreach (Match mt in oRegex.Matches(st))
   Console.WriteLine(mt.Value);
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to parse a language rather than something that can be easily parsed by a regular expression. You might be better off using a full blown parser with your own grammar https://github.com/picoe/Eto.Parse

Comment: Are you sure about any text not containing comma? Would something like `(a,b, {ab})` be a match?

Comment: @ataravati Good point. No embedded braces or parentheses. E.g. nothing like (a,b, (ab)) either. Let me update my post.

Comment: Can we assume it should be any alphanumeric character + space?

Comment: @ataravati It can contain any keyboard character other than comma, parentheses, and braces. E.g. (a,b, c + 1) is allowed.

Comment: You need to rewrite this post. The example result and the example code no longer match. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression has more problems. The following will also appear as matches, which I don't think it's what you want:

> {(a,,b),(c,,d)}
>
> {(a,b),,(c,d,e)}
>
> {(a,abcd),(abcd,b)}

Try this one:

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{\(\w(,\w)*\)(,\(\w(,\w)*\))*}");
```

**UPDATE:**
If the elements of the n-tuples can be any text not containing a comma or braces or parentheses, then you can try this:

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{\([^,(){}]+(,[^,(){}]+)*\)(,\([^,(){}]+(,[^,(){}]+)*\))*}");
```

And, if white-space around the commas between the tuples is fine (e.g. `{(a,b),  (c,d)}`), then you can use this:

```
Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"{\([^,(){}]+(,[^,(){}]+)*\)(\s*,\s*\([^,(){}]+(,[^,(){}]+)*\))*}");
```

However, this seems a lot more complicated than what you think. I'd suggest that you try to use a parser as Matthew Lock suggested in the comments.

Comment: I should have mentioned the elements of an n-tuple can be any text not containing a comma. I've edited my example and have added an EDIT at the end of my original post

Comment: @nam Just change `\w` to `[^,(){}]` (though you might want to restrict the character set further, since it allows the rest of Unicode in there).

Comment: @ataravati You are correct that this is quite complicated. I've marked your response as an answer since it's working for my cases so far at least.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks for your suggestion. It works for my example, but you are right that I may have to restrict the character set further; otherwise, it may not work for certain cases.

Comment: @nam, you're welcome. By the way, you may also want to consider for white-space between the braces and the parentheses.